# Remove row from DataTable that contains value

Tags: c#, .net, winforms, c#-4.0, c#-3.0

I want to have a row with column CtryCode equal to "MM" deleted. Is this logic above doesn't do it?

```
if (dataTableCopy.Rows[index]["CtryCode"].ToString().Trim().ToUpper().Contains("MM"))
{
    response.DataTable.Rows.RemoveAt(index + offset--);
}
```

Breakpoint is not hitting the response statement above and I could see MM row after the execution of this, strange? Please help.

Comment: what is and where did you get the parameter 'offset' from ? Did you try to remove the offset parameter ?

Comment: You should **NEVER** abbreviate your code.  `CtryCode`.  We have NO idea if that's spelled correctly.  It should be `CountryCode`.

Comment: If it's not reaching the response line it's the value being checked is not what you think it is. Why don't you write `dataTableCopy.Rows[index]["CtryCode"].ToString()` to an object so you can easily inspect what the actual value is? Then you'll be able to see easier why it's not passing the logic set in the IF statement.

Comment: Add a variable temporarily to capture the result of `dataTableCopy.Rows[index]["CtryCode"]`. What is it?

Comment: @Dan-o To be fair, this could be data from an external source

Comment: @Amicable: Thank you, will do it and check it :)

Comment: @BenAaronson: Thank you, will do it and check it :)

Comment: @BenAaronson: Sure.  But I've never met a datasource that I couldn't change the names during the query or in post.    But the real purpose was to get the OP to check their spelling.

Comment: @Dan-o: Spelling is correct really as I could check in xmlvisualizer about the column name and its data. All data are perfect and it contains MM

Answer (score 9, accepted):

To delete row that contains value try this

```
DataRow[] result = dt2.Select("CtryCode = 'mm'");
foreach (DataRow row in result)
{
    if (row["CtryCode"].ToString().Trim().ToUpper().Contains("MM"))
    dt2.Rows.Remove(row);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

If you know the index of that row, You can delete the row like this,

```
for(int i=0;i<dataTableCopy.Rows.Count-1;i++)
   {        
        if (dataTableCopy.Rows[i]["CtryCode"].ToString().Trim().ToUpper().Contains("MM"))
    {
         dataTableCopy.Rows[i].Delete();
    }
  }
```

Answer (score 0):

One liner:

```
DtDataTable.Select("ColumnSomeName = '" + SomeThingSomeValue.ToString() + "'").ToList().ForEach(row => row.Delete());
```

Tested .NET6 VS2022

Answer (score -1):

Please find the code:

```
int id=98;
DataTable dt = new DataTable();
foreach (DataRow row in dt.Rows)
{
    if(row["Id"].ToString().Trim().Contains(id.ToString()))
        dt.Rows.Remove(row);
}
```

Comment: This will remove the row all the rows containing a `1` (1, 10, 11, 12, 13, etc) in the `Id` column if `int id = 1` because `string.Contains` returns `true` if the `string` contains any substring matching the argument passed. Use `if(row["Id"].ToString().Trim() == id.ToString())` instead of `if(row["Id"].ToString().Trim().Contains(id.ToString()))`